# Regex match on script tags that DO NOT contain certain attributes

Tags: regex

I'm battling building a regular expression for a html scan. The regex should match any `<script>` html element that *does not* contain *either* the `async` *or* the `defer` attributes.

### Unit Test:

- `<script defer src="a.js">` should `not match`
- `<script src="a.js" defer>` should `not match`
- `<script src="a.js">` should `match`
- `<script async src="a.js">` should `not match`
- `<script src="a.js" async>` should `not match`

I've fiddled with a solution for setting this up on single attributes *(`^.*<script((?!defer).)*$` and `^.*<script((?!async).)*$` respectively)* and I also created one that matches if the html element *does* contain either attribute *(`<script.+(?=defer|async).+>`)* but I can't grok it the other way around.

Any ideas?

Comment: I strongly suggest that you use a proper HTML parser.  What you're trying to do is fraught with danger because there are so many cases that you're not considering, and regular expressions are not the right tool for the job.  See http://htmlparsing.com/regexes.html for examples.

Comment: Hi @AndyLester - I'm tied into a specific html scanning tool and that only allows for regex'es in the rule builder. Good thing is that it only flags matches, later to be handled by an editor/coder.

Thanks for the link, I've passed in to the colleague who manages to tool we're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your experiments were very close!

Try the following regular expression, and demonstrated with your examples [here](https://regex101.com/r/hB6uMd/11) plus a few other use cases that might occur like `<script test defer src="a.js">` or `<script test src>`.

```regex
<script(?:(?!defer|async).)*?>
```

**Explanation**

- `<script` - `<` character followed by the word `script`
- `(?:(?!defer|async).)*?` - negative lookahead for the word `defer` or `async` followed by a single character, matching multiple times if possible but preferring fewer matches (i.e. match a single character not preceded by the word `defer` or
  `async`, matching multiple times if possible but preferring fewer
  matches)
- `>` - `>` character

**Tests**

```
|--------------------------------|-----------|
| Use case                       | Matches   |
|--------------------------------|-----------|
| <script defer src="a.js">      | NO        |
| <script async src="a.js">      | NO        | 
| <script src="a.js">            | YES       |
| <script test src="a.js">       | YES       |
| <script test async src="a.js"> | NO        |
| <script src="a.js" defer>      | NO        |
| <script src="a.js" async>      | NO        |
| <script test src>              | YES       |
|--------------------------------|-----------|
```

Comment: Hi @NoodleOfDeath - thanks for that. It solved it, but I'm pretty sure I would never have figured it out myself :-)

https://regex101.com/r/vMm7TD/1 for unit test reference going forward.

Comment: I updated my answer (by adding the lazy `?` after the `*`) to address same line situations like `<script src="a.js"><script test  src="a.js">` which should result in two matches instead of one as you can see [here](https://regex101.com/r/hB6uMd/11)